# Graph API permission in Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

As per MS [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-owners?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) only **GroupMember.Read.All** permission is required to list the group owner. I assigned this API permission to my Azure AD application. however, when I run the below query it throws the 403 error. It works without "$expand=owners" parameter

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?`$expand=owners
```

Error

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
```

Also, the above graph query works if assign **Group.Read.All** permission. But I don't want to assign this permission it will allow the application to read calendars, conversations, files, and other group content of all groups.

Please note that we have more than 2 million groups in Azure AD. So running two separate queries for the group and owner will be very time-consuming.

Comment: Thanks for reaching out , if i am not wrong you are trying to get the list of all owner of group , right ? first thing would like check in the API you provided above , there is a extra single quote ( ' ) , i am not sure if that is a typo , could you please check this API and let us know if that works - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$expand=owners

Comment: could you also check your access token by decoding into jwt.io , and make sure you have GroupMember.Read.All  permission added in scopes

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment by granting **`GroupMember.Read.All`** permission and got the **`403`** error like below:***

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$expand=owners
```

***Response:***

[image]

Using **`GroupMember.Read.All`** permission, you cannot expand the owners(**$expand=owners**) but can list the owner of **specific group** like below:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/GroupID/owners
```

***Response*:**

[image]

Please **note** that you must need **`Group.Read.All`** permission to expand owners(**$expand=owners**) that includes owners of **all groups** in response.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$expand=owners
```

After granting **`Group.Read.All`** permission, got the **response** successfully like below:

***Response:***

[image]

**References:**

[Use query parameters to customize responses - Microsoft Graph | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#expand-parameter)